# for loop inside jquery-ajax function in php

Tags: php, jquery

I am doing a rating application in php,here I want to write a for loop inside a jQuery ajax function call.I dont know how the correct syntax.

PHP code I used is

```
for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
<div class="like">
<a href="#" class="like" id="1" name="up"><img src="images/likebig.png"></a>
<a href="#" class="like" id="1" name="down"><img src="images/dislike.png"></a>

 <form>
 <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['r_id'][$i]?>">
 </form>
}
</div>
```

The above code gives four results.Here I want to get the value ($_SESSION['r_id'][$i]) of each result on the click of their corresponding click

The jQuery function I used is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $(".like").click(function(e)
    {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    var name=$(this).attr("name");
    var fname = $("#fname").val();
    var lname = $("#lname").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    for(var i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {
    var rel[i] = $("#i").val();
    }
    var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&name='+ name + '&fname='+ fname + '&lname='+ lname + '&email='+ email;
     $.ajax
      ({
      type: "POST",
      url: "rate.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      });
     });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this `for(i=1;i<=4;i++)` be `for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
var rel[i] = $("#i").val();
```

to:

```
var rel[i] = $("#" + i).val();
```

alternatively you can use [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method:

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It operates on a jQuery object representing a set of form elements. The form elements can be of several types:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "rate.php",
   data: $('form').serialize(),
   cache: false,
 });
```

Comment: sorry but how did this answer the for-loop "question"?

Comment: @tradyblix his for loop syntax is correct i think he wants `$("#" + i)` instead of `$("#i")`.

Comment: @undefined Hi friend Thnks for your answer.But when I tried to alert the value it shows error "missing ; before statement" in firebug error console

Comment: @undefined Hi.I changed the line [var rel[i] = $("#i").val();] to [var rel[i] = $("#" + i).val();] and tried to alert the value rel[1].

Comment: @Balu define the `rel[]` array outside of the for loop in each iteration you are defining it again and again. do you have form elements by id `#2` `#3` ... ? if no, the array values will be `undefined`.

Comment: @undefined Hi friend.You are right.Its working fine now.But I need the value of the particular result,how can i know that in which result,user clicks...